# Apache redirect to main URL on Query

Tags: linux, apache

I have requirement to redirect Apache on query base parameters for example

`https://example.com/?ampostpreserve=01902018`

I need to redirect to `https://example.com` .. I tried with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ampostpreserv$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com [R=301,L]
```

but seem not working ..any solution

Thanks Hem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to drop the query string? The QSD parameter does exactly that. The below version is for every called URL.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,L,R=301]
```

And this is the specific version for example.com and the above query string:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ampostpreserve
  RewriteRule .* https://example.com [QSD,L,R=301]
```